# How can I reset the prompt of my machine before using tramp without having this setting being permanent?

Tags: tramp

I have a cool looking (at least for me) prompt for my bash shell. This mean that tramp hangs if I try to use sudo to open a file because my prompt looks like something unexpected to tramp. And I really don't like to deal with regexp.

So, I was wondering how can I reset the prompt of my machine before using tramp!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the `.bashrc` such that it doesn't modify the prompt when the `TERM` variable is set to "dumb".

```
if test $TERM = "dumb"
   # leave the prompt alone
else
   # set up fancy prompt
end
```

According to the manual `TERM` is governed by `tramp-terminal-type`, which defaults to `dumb`.

Comment: I think that this is the best solution possible short of fixing dumb terminals in general. Not only will it fix it with tramp, but also other dumb terminals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, rekado, but how I tell Tramp to set the $TERM variable before doing anything?

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro according to the manual `TERM` is governed by `tramp-terminal-type`, which defaults to `dumb`.